# Where is the real location of data when using symlinks?

Tags: symbolic-link

When you create a symlink using mklink /D Link Target where does the real data exist? Where the target is right ? what about the hard link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you create a symlink using mklink /D Link Target where does the real data exist? Where the target is right ?

It continues to exist at the target only. The reason symlinks are called *symbolic* links is that they just redirect to another path (the target) – they have nothing of their own.

Junctions work the same way (with very minor differences).

> what about the hard link?

Hard links are the opposite; they are literally additional names for the same file. There is still only one file and only one copy of the data, but it has two names (or however many names you add), and neither of them is "the original" – the file only gets deleted once you delete *all* of the names (links) it had.

(It's why you can't create hard links across different disks.)